# Call updated price based on dates and not changing the older lookup

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have table A as a master pricing. I put the master price here and sometimes I update them every month.

And then I have another table, to record my sales. In this sales table, I input date, product name, and it calls the price by looking up from table A, the master price.

But, every month, as I said I will update the price, I want in sales table, it just look up updated price based on product name and latest date. Meanwhile, my older data in sales table, is not changing.

I have tried by using QUERY but it looks like cannot work as arrayformula, as every row is unique and I do not want to copy paste it all over the rows in my sales table. I tried using XLOOKUP but it changes my older data too in sales table.

I want the formula as simple as possible, using arrayformula if it can, so I do not need to copy paste all the formula into all my rows in sales table.

I give up and now I ask you smart guys here to help me solving my problem. You can access my spreadsheet to see what I expect from this question: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17iF81FDsQBL0XVgIrWoPb5Bg8tuMPpcfS2QHa1ZPLyI/edit?usp=sharing[Call](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17iF81FDsQBL0XVgIrWoPb5Bg8tuMPpcfS2QHa1ZPLyI/edit?usp=sharing%5BCall) only the updated price based on product and date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veSC1.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able use `XLOOKUP` for this.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(XLOOKUP($F$3:$F&$E$3:$E,$B$3:$B&$A$3:$A,$C$3:$C,,-1))`

We are looking up the product and the date, in the corresponding master list and returning column C (price). If an exact date match is not found then it returns the next value lower (October 2nd is not listed so we find October 1st).

The caveat is that this assumes a Product will be in the list. If you added a "Product D" in the Sales Record, it will return a value of "$160" (last value regardless of date) as in the closest value to Product D is Product C. There really isn't a way to indicate when no match is found when using a match_mode -1.

- **match_mode - [optional]** How to find a match for the search_key. 0 is
  for an exact match, 1 for an exact match or the next value that is
  bigger than the search_key, -1 for an exact match or the next value
  that is lower than the search_key, and 2 for a wildcard match. If
  unspecified, this defaults to finding an exact match.